# How to infer tuple index 0 in two-dimensional array of tuple to literal type?

Tags: typescript

I have an array type of tuple, how to make TypeScript infer the index 0 of tuples as a union?

Example:

```
type KV = [string, string];
type KVs = KV[];

function sample(param: KVs) {
  return param.map(([key]) => key);
}

// here result is: string[]
const result = sample([
  ["a", "b"],
  ["c", "d"],
]);
```

How can I make the result type be an array of `"a" | "c"`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use generics:

```
type KV<T extends string, U extends string> = [T, U];

function sample<T extends string, U extends string>(param: KV<T, U>[]) {
  return param.map(([key]) => key);
}

// result: ("a" | "c")[]
const result = sample([
  ["a", "b"],
  ["c", "d"],
]);
```

This types `KV` as a tuple with two generic parameters, both which must be strings, but could also be a narrower type like a string literal. In this case, TypeScript will choose the narrowest type for a given use.

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA0gagHgCpQgD2BAdgEwM5R7ABOAllgOYA0UAqqhtvoSeRQHxQC8UA2kjVoBdANwAoMQDMArlgDGwUgHsshAIYBbMABsIyBplwEiZSoINNjrSuwAUYNcU0AuWIgF12vIQEooAbzEoKGIIYGliVQcnDQA6DTUwW1teAGsIEF9uTnSQH3EAXwk5FSIQiDxpbWBudS1dFKDg5oB6FqgAPQB+Jt4AIjU+mj6AIz6hKl6+uSGoPpxxyd8RIA)

Comment: Nice! I didn't think we'd be able to do it without `as const`. Now I can't think why I thought that...